# Passing multiple object into an array as 1d

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am having little problem passing the data in correct way. Here my form is coming as {comment:'this is my comment'} and id is coming as number. I need to post them to backend.

```
    let arr = [];
    let obj = {};

    obj['id'] = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
    arr.push(this.form, obj);
```

I am getting data like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [comment] => this is my comment
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
        )

)
```

I am looking for single dimensional array instead. I can convert the array in backend but I am looking if there is better way to post data.

Comment: needs more clear explanation where those comment came from

Comment: Is it possible to post mutiple comments and ids at the same time with your form? If so, how does the structure look like then?

Comment: well you could assign it into the array `arr['key'] = value here`

Comment: how does your original array looks and what is your goal or desired result of an array

Comment: `var data = {
 id: this.route.snapshot.params.id,
 comment: this.form.comment
};`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if your goal is to make it something like this

```
{
    comment: 'this is comment',
    id: 3
}
```

well you don't need to create an array, just stored them in an object

don't complicate your self it's just a simple as this

```
var data = {
    comment: this.form.comment
    id: this.route.snapshot.params.id,
};
```

Comment: thank you it turn out to very easy.. i was making myself complicated more

Answer (score 0):

```
arr['id'] = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
arr['comment'] = this.form['comment'];
```

Comment: at the moment i get arr
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {comment: "my comment"}
1: {id: "3"} i am looking for {comment: mycomment', id: 3}

Comment: @SS to avoid confusion please can you use square brackets when referring to arrays and curly for objects, thanks. And I'll edit my answer to meet that requirement

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21242804)

Comment: @ponury-kostek this does answer the question, it gives the exact same output as the accepted answer with the exception of using an array instead of an object. However he asked for an array, if anything the accepted answer is less correct. Also if you want to go back, my original answer still answered OP's question, he just left wiggle room open to multiple answers. When he clarified the answer he wanted on my post I improved it.

Answer (score 0):

```
obj['id'] = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
obj['comment'] = *your comment*;

arr.push(obj);
```